# Loading c# DLLs/assemblies securely

Tags: c#

I'm working on a "plugin" system for a C# application. Developers will be able to write C# plugins using our API and then users can add those DLLs to an application folder, which our app will then scan/verify and load (with `Assembly.LoadFrom`)

Before I go further I'm trying to understand the security best practices I need to be aware of. I can find a lot about generating secured DLLs, but I want to do my best to *load* DLLs securely.

Is there a way I can load each DLL in some isolated/locked-down context? Is that what application domains are intended for?

I believe that's accurate, but am I reading correctly that I have to essentially interact with those files via reflection only?

For example here's an example from Microsoft's technet:

```
public class Loader : MarshalByRefObject
{
    object CallInternal(string dll, string typename, string method, object[] parameters)
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
        object o = a.CreateInstance(typename);
        Type t = o.GetType();
        MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod(method);
        return m.Invoke(o, parameters);
    }
    public static object Call(string dll, string typename, string method, params object[] parameters)
    {
        AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyNewDomain");
        Loader ld = (Loader)dom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(Loader).FullName);
        object result = ld.CallInternal(dll, typename, method, parameters);
        AppDomain.Unload(dom);
        return result;
    }
}
```

That's a lot less user-friendly than I'd like. I don't mind so much on the application side, but if developers write mods that integrate with each other they'd have to use some equivalent of this.

Also... Do I need to worry about (if even possible) disallowing access to certain systems? If they write code that reads files, is it possible for me to prevent them from reading anything outside the application root?

Comment: That security is always so inconvenient is the bigger reason why there is so little of it around.  Getting the user to pay for it is another one.

Comment: See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading)